# Mysql - Convert date string to real date when we have timezone in the string

Tags: mysql, string, date, timezone

How can I convert the following varchar to actual date in MySQL ?

```
"Thu Nov 07 15:05:22 EST 2013"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that this will solve my problem if I dont care about the time zone:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( concat( substr( 'Thu Nov 07 15:05:22 est 2013', 1, 20 ) , substr( 'Thu Nov 07 15:05:22 est 2013', 25, 4 ) ) , '%W %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y' );
```

However if I want I can take out the "est" part and covert that either.